# grep command in Bash

Tags: bash, unix

I've written the following function in Bash:

```
function findTest {
 files=`ls $1`
 for file in ${files[*]}; do
    if [[ "$file"=="*.tst" ]]; then
        grep "version: $2" $1/$file
        if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
            echo -n $2
            grep "result" | cut -d ":" -f2 
        fi
    fi  
 done
}
```

for some odd reason, the line `grep "version: $2" $1/$file` claims that `$1/$file` isn't a file/directory, yet I know for a fact that $1 contains an address of directory which $file exsists in. Is there any rational reason why

Comment: try `grep "version: $2" "$1/$file"`

Comment: `files=\`ls $1\`` is not creating an array. You want `files=($1)` or `files=("$1"/*)` if `$1` is a directory to do that.

Comment: I'd turn on set -x so you could see the expanded version of the command it's running, perhaps it's not expanding as you think.  Also, if any of your file names have spaces you're going to have trouble going this route

Comment: Once you get an actual array you want to use `for file in "${files[@]}"` as the loop to correctly handle spaces, etc. in the filenames. You also need spaces around the `==` in the `[[` test or you are testing that the entire string is non-empty (which it clearly isn't).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than trying to run `ls` and parse it's output better to use globbing and list files of a an extension in `for` loop:

```
findTest() {
  for file in "$1"/*.tst; do
      if grep -q "version: $2" "$file"; then
          echo "grep succeded"
      fi
  done
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of issues with the snippet as posted.

http://www.shellcheck.net finds many of them.

```
 1  function findTest {
 2   files=`ls $1`
             ^––SC2006 Use $(..) instead of legacy `..`.
                 ^––SC2086 Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.
 3   for file in ${files[*]}; do
 4      if [[ "$file"=="*.tst" ]]; then
                ^––SC2077 You need spaces around the comparison operator.
                       ^––SC2140 The double quotes around this do nothing. Remove or escape them.
 5          grep "version: $2" $1/$file
                                 ^––SC2086 Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.
                                    ^––SC2086 Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.
 6          if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
 7              echo -n $2
                          ^––SC2086 Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.
 8              grep "result" | cut -d ":" -f2 
 9          fi
10      fi  
11   done
12  }
```

The things it doesn't find are things like [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and that `files` isn't an array like you appear to have been trying to create or that `${files[*]}` (assuming it was an array) would be less useful than `"${files[@]}"` since the `*` version (quoted or not) doesn't handle files with spaces in the names, etc.

Comment: One more problem: the command `grep "result"` doesn't have an input file specified, so it'll hang waiting for terminal input. I'm pretty sure that's not the intended behavior, but I'm not sure what it's supposed to do either...

Comment: @GordonDavisson:  I think the OP is trying to remove the filename from the `grep` output, and is obviously unaware of bash string expansions.